# How can I obtain previous values in a pipeline using generators?

Tags: python, iterator, generator

I'm using some generators to build a processing pipeline in Python. However, I noticed that after several processing steps, I need a value that was computed previously (in a previous generator.) As an example:

```
from itertools import izip, tee

# first generator
def gen():
    for i in range(10):
        yield i
# second generator that uses gen's values
def gen2(x):
    for i in x:
        yield i**2

# third generator that requires values from gen and gen2
def gen3(iter_, iter_2):
    for iter1, iter2 in izip(iter_, iter_2):
        yield iter1*iter2
```

I would use it like this:

```
x, x_2 = tee(gen())
y = gen2(x)
z = gen3(x_2, y)

next(z)
```

There are a couple of issues, though.

1. I need to create a copy of `gen`'s values because the second generator consumes the values that also need to be used by `gen3`.
2. It is a bit awkward to try to obtain previous values in a pipeline. It doesn't seem to be something that generators are suitable for.

The pipeline I have requires previous values only once, so I'm a bit hesitant to use OOP for this situation. I can't really use a list instead of a generator in most steps, because memory consumption would be too high. What is a good way to address this issue?

Comment: If you need to consume a value more than once, it is probably better to have them in a persistent data structure, like `list` instead of trying to force a generator to handle it. In fact, the need for a value more than one time is one of the overriding considerations described when people write polemics about when to use a list vs. when to use a generator. So, in short, why not also store your values to a list as you consume them? If only a small subset needs to be stored (based on known-in-advance, or easily computable, properties) then just store those specific generator outputs.

Comment: I thought about it, but if I create a list of all those values,  memory consumption would be a problem because I'm dealing with arrays of images.

Comment: It isn't important that it is images, it could be just a stream of integers if it was large enough. The point is that you are running into a fundamental problem. How do you repeatedly consume values from a data supply that is too big to fit into memory? There are many answers: split your data up into segments that don't have to be processed together, such that for each segment the data is small enough to fit in memory, possibly distributing to many processors. Or you can simulate swapping by loading just some of the data, saving what you need, then continuing.

Comment: @Eithos Well, I'm using one value (an iterator of arrays) in another generator after a few steps in the pipeline. Other than that, the generators consume previous iterators without requiring other values.

Comment: Yield can return tuples, so you can have your second generator yield "i,i**2", then the third generator gets both values instead of just the result of the second generator.

Comment: @swstephe But, for anything beyond a trivial problem, you'll be building in a dependence on chaining a computed value, and all the args that went into its computation, all the time. You'll be passing an increasingly complicated set of values to each function in the sequence. In this example it's simple, an index and the square of the index. But for image processing, this would be quite a bit worse.

Comment: @swstephe Oh, yes, I tried that approach, but I think there is a problem because I'm not sure the second generator contains both arrays I need in the third generator. I will check that again.

Comment: @swstephe Yes, I just confirmed the second generator doesn't contain the arrays I need in the third generator.

Comment: @prpl.mnky.dshwshr Well, this case is fundamentally a pipeline and I would be able to process everything in a single machine in a reasonable amount of time. Therefore, I don't want to give up that simplicity by splitting the data if I don't have to. However, you can also argue that the data is already split in very manageable units.